# New RØDE i16. Is it an april fool?

Tags: rode, surround-sound, field-recording

http://www.rodemic.com/news/new-rode-i16-offer-360-surround-recording-for-ios-devices

Comment: Definitely. That's just too absurd.

Answer (score 2):

They have achieved their goal: We talk about it.

Answer (score 2):

"get a man bag" classic - has to be a joke ;)

Answer (score 1):

After 15ms of just astounding joy,      yeh it must be :P 
Although what really annoyed me, was they went to the lengths of saying its a lightening adapter, which isn't even true for the iXY (and god I want it to be)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely an April fool.

Answer (score 1):

Naaaaaaah...looks legit to me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

They release this video 1 day before the April Fools, it has to be one!

Comment: Aren't Rode based in Australia? Could well have been 1st April there by the time this was posted! 